# Erro no código de uma calculadora ao guardar os tokens, flex

Tags: visual-studio, compiladores, flex

O erro mencionado está na 6ª linha de código. Ao executar este código no desenvolvedor do *VS* com o *win_flex o TOKEN_B* não é reconhecido mostrando, deste modo, um resultado errado.

```
%option nounistd noyywrap
#include <stdio.h>

enum {TOKEN_A, TOKEN_B, TOKEN_SOMA, TOKEN_SUBT, TOKEN_MULT, TOKEN_DIVI, TOKEN_MISC, TOKEN_EOF };
%%
    [0-9]+([.][0-9]+)*  return TOKEN_A, TOKEN_B;   
    [+]                 return TOKEN_SOMA;          
    [-]                 return TOKEN_SUBT;      
    [/]                 return TOKEN_DIVI;          
    [*]                 return TOKEN_MULT;  
    .|\r|\n             return TOKEN_MISC; 
    <<EOF>>             return TOKEN_EOF;
%%

main()
{
    int num_a=TOKEN_A;
    int num_b=TOKEN_B;
    int token;

    do {
        switch( token=yylex())
            {
            case TOKEN_SOMA:    printf("O resultado e' : %d \n", num_a + num_b);
                                break;
            case TOKEN_SUBT:    printf("O resultado e' : %d \n", num_a - num_b);
                                break;
            case TOKEN_DIVI:    printf("O resultado e' : %d \n", num_a / num_b);
                                break;
            case TOKEN_MULT:    printf("O resultado e' : %d \n", num_a * num_b);
                                break;
            /* outro TOKEN_*: ignora */
        }
    } while( token != TOKEN_EOF );
    return 0;
}
```